# Trying to make a next button in Java using Netbeans - quiz game

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I made a quiz game and I'm having a problem with the next button. The next button must go to the next question and the next answers. After the first execution of next button it will go to the first question and answers but will not continue to the second question and answers.

guiandtests3.java
    package guiandtests3;

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Random;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class Guiandtests3 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
       gui3 form = new gui3();
       form.setVisible(true);

       Random random = new Random();
        int a = random.nextInt(3+1-0)+0;
        int b = random.nextInt(3+1-0)+0;
        int c = random.nextInt(3+1-0)+0;
        int d = random.nextInt(3+1-0)+0;


       JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
       Object obj = null;
       obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("c:\\Matematika.json"));
       JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
       JSONArray array = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("data");

       Iterator<Object> iterator = array.iterator();
       //form.s11();
       while (iterator.hasNext() ) {
              //System.out.println("a");
              if (form.getter()==form.g11()){
                  //System.out.println("abc");
                JSONObject element=(JSONObject)iterator.next();
                JSONArray abc = (JSONArray) element.get("jawaban");
                Iterator<Object> iterator1 = abc.iterator();
                ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<>();

                System.out.println(element.get("soal"));

                form.setquestion((String) element.get("soal"));


               while (iterator1.hasNext()) {

                           results.add(iterator1.next().toString());
                           //System.out.println(iterator1.next());
                        }


               System.out.println(results.get(0));
                       System.out.println(results.get(1));

               while(a==b){
                           b = random.nextInt(3+1-0)+0;
                       }
                       while(a==c | b ==c){
                           c = random.nextInt(3+1-0)+0;
                       }
                       while(a==d | b ==d |c==d){
                           d = random.nextInt(3+1-0)+0;
                       }
                       form.setAnswer1(results.get(a));
                       form.setAnswer2(results.get(b));
                       form.setAnswer3(results.get(c));
                       form.setAnswer4(results.get(d));

                       form.setanswer(results.get(0));
                form.s11();
              }

    }

    }

}
```

gui3.java

```
package guiandtests3;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
/**
 *
 * @author abc
 */
public class gui3 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public  String question;
    public  String answer1;
    public  String answer2;
    public  String answer3;
    public  String answer4;

    private int i=0;
    private int aa=0;
    private String correctanswer="empty";

    public gui3() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public void setanswer(String answer){
        correctanswer = answer;
    }

    public String getanswer(){
        return correctanswer;
    }

    public void setter(){
        this.i = this.i +1;
    }

    public int getter(){
        return this.i;
    }

    public void s11(){
        this.aa=this.aa+1;
    }
    public int g11(){
        return this.aa;
    }

    public void setAnswer1(String answer){
        this.answer1=answer;
    }

    public String getAnswer1(){
        return this.answer1;
    }

    public void setAnswer2(String answer){
        this.answer2= answer;
    }

    public String getAsnwer2(){
        return this.answer2;
    }

    public void setAnswer3(String answer){
        this.answer3= answer;
    }

    public String getAsnwer3(){
        return this.answer3;
    }

    public void setAnswer4(String answer){
        this.answer4= answer;
    }

    public String getAsnwer4(){
        return this.answer4;
    }

    public void setquestion(String question){
        this.question=question;
    }

    public String getquestion(){
        return this.question;
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("jButton2");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton3.setText("jButton3");
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton4.setText("jButton4");
        jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton5.setText("Next");
        jButton5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton5ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(176, 176, 176)
                                .addComponent(jLabel1))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(156, 156, 156)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(jButton2)
                                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                                    .addComponent(jButton3)
                                    .addComponent(jButton4))))
                        .addGap(0, 161, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton5)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(47, 47, 47)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jButton3)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jButton4)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jButton5)
                .addContainerGap(34, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,getanswer(),null,JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        if(jButton1.getText() == getanswer() ){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,"Correct",null,JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,"Wrong",null,JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        if(jButton2.getText() == getanswer() ){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,"Correct",null,JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,"Wrong",null,JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }                                        

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        if(jButton3.getText() == getanswer() ){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,"Correct",null,JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,"Wrong",null,JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }                                        

    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        if(jButton4.getText() == getanswer() ){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,"Correct",null,JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,"Wrong",null,JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }                                        

    private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        jLabel1.setText(question);
        jButton1.setText(answer1);
        jButton2.setText(answer2);
        jButton3.setText(answer3);
        jButton4.setText(answer4);
        setter();
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(gui3.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(gui3.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(gui3.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(gui3.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new gui3().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

json file

```
{
"data":[
{
    "id":"1",
    "soal":"3 * 3 + 2 =",
    "jawaban":[
        "11",
        "15",
        "17",
        "19"
    ]

},
{
    "id":"2",
    "soal":"20 / 5 =",
    "jawaban":[
        "4",
        "3",
        "2",
        "1"
    ]
},
{
    "id":"3",
    "soal":"16 + 6 = ",
    "jawaban":[
        "22",
        "21",
        "20",
        "24"
    ]
},
{
    "id":"4",
    "soal":"2 * 4 =",
    "jawaban":[
        "8",
        "6",
        "10",
        "12"
    ]
},
{
    "id":"5",
    "soal":"1+4*2",
    "jawaban":[
        "8",
        "10",
        "12",
        "14"
    ]
},
{
    "id":"6",
    "soal":"Jika A+1=10 , B+A=11 C= ?",
    "jawaban":[
        "EGP",
        "1",
        "12",
        "22"
    ]
},
{
    "id":"7",
    "soal":"44/11",
    "jawaban":[
        "4",
        "2",
        "5",
        "8"
    ]
},
{
    "id":"8",
    "soal":"1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1 = ",
    "jawaban":[
        "16",
        "15",
        "17",
        "10"
    ]
},
{
    "id":"9",
    "soal":"Berapakah jawaban sebelumnya ",
    "jawaban":[
        "16",
        "17",
        "18",
        "19"
    ]
}
]
}
```

[press to see the GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymNRj.png)

Comment: You never increase your index. However I would recommend you to take a look at [Card Layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) and learn to use it. Also to forget of NetBeans GUI builder until you know what it's doing.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass your questions and answers into your gui object so the iterator can actually move to the next 'result'.

You should be moving to the next result within your next button rather than from your main function as your gui has no access to those questions and nothing from within the gui can get information from the results you collected in your main from the data file.

Consider moving the initial read of the file from the main function to the 'gui3' object constructor and making the 'results' ArrayList available as an instance variable of the gui.

This first read of the JSON file is exceptionally confusing with the random numbers you're using, but you're going to want to figure out a way to line up a question with the answers in a single array.

Example:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>  results = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> question = new ArrayList<>()
question.add(question);
question.add(answer1);
question.add(answer2);
question.add(answer3);
question.add(answer4);
results.add(questions);
```

Then when you do the button 'next' press, you can

```
jLabel1.setText(results.get(i).get(0));
jButton1.setText(results.get(i).get(1));
jButton2.setText(results.get(i).get(2));
jButton3.setText(results.get(i).get(3));
jButton4.setText(results.get(i).get(4));
i++;  // Or use your setter() function?
```

Based on the question in the comments as to how to get the JSON into the array list, it is very similar to how you are doing it now, but you need to 'add' it to the ArrayList instead of using it immediately.

Something like:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
Object obj = null;
obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("c:\\Matematika.json"));
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
JSONArray array = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("data");
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>  results = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> question = new ArrayList<>();

Iterator<Object> iterator = array.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext() ) {
    String questionString = element.get("soal");
    question.add(questionString);
    JSONArray answers = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("jawaban");
    Iterator<String> iterator2 = answers.iterator();
    int count = 0;
    //The following limits it to pulling back 4 answers from the JSON jawaban element
    while (iterator2.hasNext() && count < 4) {
        String answer = iterator2.next();
        question.add(answer);
        count++;
    }
    results.add(question);
}
```

Place this code in the constructor of your gui3 object - or pass this into your gui3 constructor and make the constructor the results like this:

```
public class gui3 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> results;

    //Your other code here

    public gui3(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> results) {
        this.results = results;
        initComponents();
    }

    // Your other code here
}
```

Note that you will need this results ArrayList to be in the Class Instance scope, so you'll need to move the declaration outside of the constructor.

Comment: how to pass the json into ArrayList ?

Comment: I've updated to include how to feed the JSON results into the ArrayList

Comment: with the method "add()" you mean that I need to code a new method "add()" ?

Comment: No, the add is already a method included in the ArrayList object. You are just using the add method of ArrayList to add it to the collection for use later.

Comment: the part of code "Something like:" i can not understand it.It throws many errors.May you write it more correctly please

Comment: You may need to "import java.util.ArrayList" if your IDE doesn't already do it for you.

Comment: i have errors with this 2 lines of code:
String question = element.get("soal");
    question.add(question);

Comment: Ahh, yeah, I was trying to adapt my code with your code and accidentally named the variables the same thing.  I've fixed it by renaming the String "question" to "questionString"

Comment: what is "element" in"element.get("soal");" ? It give me error.Can you fix it?